# How do I assign optional to an angular Object in Interface/Model?

Tags: angular, angular14

```
Angular Version: "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
```

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age?: number;
  address?: { <<----- my issue/problem is on this area 
   street?: string;
   city?: string;
   state?: string;
 };
 isActive?: boolean;
 registered?: any;
 hide?: true;
}
```

```
//users.component.html
```

[image]
because every time I assign optional to address object (?) I get undifined [image]

My Objective are:

- I want it to the address object to be optional
  without the error of
- Object is possibly 'undefined'
- is there a another way to of doing this?

Comment: Try `user?.address?.street`

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{ user?.address?.street || ''}}